# Opening Times List To Highlight Day

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a list of opening times:

Mon 09:00 - 17:00
Tue 09:00 - 17:00
etc

I'd like to know if anyone can tell me where I can find tutorials on how to highlight the opening times for the day we are on. IE On Tuesday the line Tue 09:00 - 17:00 would be in green and the rest in the normal font colour.

Any help appreciated, I tend to find articles about calendars, which isn't what I want.

Cheers

Comment: I trust you're familiar with timezones, and the associated headaches that come with them?

Comment: @BenM true, forgot about time zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="mon">Mon 09:00 - 17:00</li>
    <li id="tue">Tue 09:00 - 17:00</li>
    <li id="wed">Wed 09:00 - 17:00</li>
    <li id="thu">Thu 09:00 - 17:00</li>
    <li id="fri">Fri 09:00 - 17:00</li>
    <li id="sat">Sat 09:00 - 12:00</li>
    <li id="sun">Sun 09:00 - 12:00</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var n = new Date();
var d = n.getDay();

if(d==0) document.getElementById('sun').style.color='#0b0';
if(d==1) document.getElementById('mon').style.color='#0b0';
if(d==2) document.getElementById('tue').style.color='#0b0';
if(d==3) document.getElementById('wed').style.color='#0b0';
if(d==4) document.getElementById('thu').style.color='#0b0';
if(d==5) document.getElementById('fri').style.color='#0b0';
if(d==6) document.getElementById('sat').style.color='#0b0';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4wwmL09a/

---

Edit: so Marco was first...

Answer (score 0):

You should have an HTML structure like the following:

```
<ul id="opening-times">
    <li>Sun 09:00 - 17:00</li>
    <li>Mon 09:00 - 15:00</li>
    <li>Tue 08:00 - 19:00</li>
    <li>Wed 09:00 - 20:00</li>
    <li>Thu 09:00 - 20:00</li>
    <li>Fri 09:00 - 20:00</li>
    <li>Sat 15:00 - 20:00</li>
</ul>
```

Then with JavaScript you can do something like this to highlight the current day:

```
var days = document.getElementById("opening-times"),
    today = new Date().getDay(); // 0 to 6 where 0 is Sunday

days.children[today].style.color = "green";
```

If you want to put Monday first, then move Sunday at the bottom of the list and use this code:

```
var days = document.getElementById("opening-times"),
    today = new Date().getDay()-1;

if (today===-1) today = 6; // sunday
days.children[today].style.color = "green";
```